# Spring profiles: Deny user tu run many profiles from same "group"

Tags: spring

I would like to conditioner profiles. 
For example I have Two groups of profiles:
a) DEV, PROD, TEST
b) ProfileDB1, ProfileDB2, ProfileDB3

I would like to force that application will be run with one profile of first group, and one profile of second group. But no more.  Is it possible ?

Comment: you want to run single instace of app or more than one instance?You can run two instance of app with different group of profile but at any given point of time it will take only one profile in the group as master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ApplicationListener that to check when the application is prepared that the profiles are as expected before the rest of the application loads.

```
public class ProfileValidator implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileValidator.class);

    private static final Set<String> DB_PROFILES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("DB1", "DB2", "DB3"));

    private static final Set<String> ENVIRONMENT_PROFILES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("dev", "test"));


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent applicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
        List<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(applicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles());

        LOG.info("Validating Allowed Profiles - {}", activeProfiles);

        if (activeProfiles.size() > 1) {
            long count = activeProfiles.stream().filter(profile -> DB_PROFILES.contains(profile) || ENVIRONMENT_PROFILES.contains(profile)).count();

            LOG.debug("Counted {} profiles", count);

            if (count != 0 && activeProfiles.size() - 2 != (activeProfiles.size() - count)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid Profiles detected for %s", activeProfiles.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working example,

https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/spring-profile-validator

Note the `spring.factories` to register the `ApplicationListener`. There's also a test class to verify the functionality, and can just start it up with invalid combos or not.

Comment: hmm this I like also...  Dont know which solution is better. Yours or Michiel's

Comment: This works before any beans etc. will init, you'll fail faster and avoid any issues of other configurations running e.g. Liquibase trying to connect.

Comment: It's perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write some kind of an ActiveProfilesVerifier component in which the `Environment` is injected and the active profiles are verified:

```java
@Component
public class ActiveProfilesVerifier {

    private static final List<String> ENV_PROFILES = Arrays.asList("DEV", "PROD", "TEST");
    private static final List<String> DBASE_PROFILES = Arrays.asList("ProfileDB1", "ProfileDB2", "ProfileDB3");

    private final Environment environment;

    public ActiveProfilesVerifier(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void verifyProfiles() {
        String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();

        boolean hasSingleEnvProfile = Arrays.stream(activeProfiles).filter(ENV_PROFILES::contains).count() == 1;
        if (!hasSingleEnvProfile) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Select exactly one environment profile");
        }

        boolean hasSingleDbaseProfile = Arrays.stream(activeProfiles).filter(DBASE_PROFILES::contains).count() == 1;
        if (!hasSingleDbaseProfile) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Select exactly one database profile");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks great. But maybe better then @component will be configuration?